# Get current location Android Kotlin

Tags: android, google-maps, kotlin, maps, currentlocation

I try to get the current Location with GM API in my application (using Android Studio). But if i click the button which triggers the getLocation() funktion, i always end up in the catch{} block and i dont know why.
My mobile device is connected for testing.

Here is the getLocation() Funktion:

```
fun getLocation() {

    var locationManager = getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE) as LocationManager?

    var locationListener = object : LocationListener{
        override fun onLocationChanged(location: Location?) {
            var latitute = location!!.latitude
            var longitute = location!!.longitude

            Log.i("test", "Latitute: $latitute ; Longitute: $longitute")

        }

        override fun onStatusChanged(provider: String?, status: Int, extras: Bundle?) {
        }

        override fun onProviderEnabled(provider: String?) {
        }

        override fun onProviderDisabled(provider: String?) {
        }

    }

    try {
        locationManager!!.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0L, 0f, locationListener)
    } catch (ex:SecurityException) {
        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Fehler bei der Erfassung!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
```

Here is the onCreate Funktion:

```
class CurrentLocationActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


lateinit var mapFragment : SupportMapFragment
lateinit var googleMap : GoogleMap

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_current_location)

    //Karte erstellen
    mapFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map) as SupportMapFragment
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(OnMapReadyCallback {
        googleMap = it
    })



    //OnClickListener um Location zu speichern
    btnGetCurrentLocation.setOnClickListener {
        getLocation()
    }
}
```

Comment: Check if location permission is granted

Comment: Somehow I can't check for permission.
If i click Alt + Enter and click on add permission check nothing happens.
Also if i type in manual, AndroidStudio says in Manifest.permission, that ist a unresolved reference: permission

Comment: Try manually set permission to access location on `Settings > Apps > Your App > Info > Permissions`. If it work, we will discovery the problem and I will put the solution to you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try as follow

**Step 1.** Put on your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com....">

    <!-- This line -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application ... />

</manifest>
```

**Step 2.** Put it above your location request

```
import android.Manifest
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat

...

fun getLocation() {

    ...

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                this,
                arrayOf(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION),
                PERMISSION_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
        return
    }
    locationManager!!.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0L, 0f, locationListener)
}

override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<out String>, grantResults: IntArray) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
    if (requestCode == PERMISSION_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) {
        when (grantResults[0]) {
            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED -> getLocation()
            PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED -> //Tell to user the need of grant permission
        }
    }
}

companion object {
    private const val PERMISSION_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION = 100
}
```

Comment: I still get "unresolved reference: permission" on Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION

Also I've got "unresolvede reference" on PERMISSION_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION

Comment: PERMISSION_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION now works, but "unresolved reference: permission" on Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION didnt't disappear.

Comment: Remove this call `import java.util.jar.Manifest` and it will work

Comment: Thank you man this worked!!
I Imported android.Manifest instead

Answer (score 1):

The [LocationManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager) will throw a SecurityException if the location permission has not been granted.

Information on adding the location permissions to your app can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/location).

Comment: I've noticed that Site, but also if I copy the code I always get the "unresolved reference: permission" in
Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION

Comment: You probably imported java.util.jar.Manifest instead of android.Manifest

Comment: I have. Here are my Imports:
import android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.location.Location
import android.location.LocationListener
import android.location.LocationManager
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission

Comment: import android.util.Log
import android.widget.Toast
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_current_location.*
import java.util.jar.Manifest