# Kotlin: How to get current location?

Tags: android, kotlin, gps

I'm trying to get actual location. I readed and tried dozens of examples. But all ends with error.

Example:
`val locationManager = context.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE) as LocationManager`

Ends with this error:
`Only safe (?.) or non-null asserted (!!.) calls are allowed on a nullable receiver of type Context?`

Or I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51313359/get-current-location-android-kotlin). But `ActivityCompat` and `content` are red in Android studio.

I tried xx versions but some error was always there.

I'm creating GPS tracker. I'm starting with simple location detection.

Do you know some example for Android studio 4.1.2?

Answer (score 0):

```
Only safe (?.) or non-null asserted (!!.) calls are allowed on a nullable receiver of type Context?
```

This means that the variable `context` is of a Kotlin [nullable type](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html). In Kotlin, unlike Java, you need to specify whether a variable can be null or not. Accessing such a variable is done through the syntax `variable?.method()` to signify that you understand that the call may evaluate to null.

So in your example, it would look like:

```
val locationManager = context?.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE) as? LocationManager
```

Since `locationManager` was assigned a nullable type, it is now also nullable. You could mitigate this by doing something like:

```
val locationManager = (context?.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE) as? LocationManager) ?: error("Could not get LocationManager")
```

Comment: Understand. It works, thanks! But how to get details from `locationManager` variable? I'm trying `getLatitude()` or `getLongitude()` - without success  .

Comment: https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/android/docs/training/basics/location/locationmanager.html
https://www.codota.com/code/java/how-to/finding-current-android-device-location

Comment: Thanks! After hours and hours it works! I'm excited from Kotlin.